# Is it possible to show tool-tip for Column on Magento grid?

Tags: magento-1.8

I have created custom grid in Admin panel to display a question/answers..

For Columns, I am displaying the question id instead of the question text.

And answers are shown in row for each customer.

I want to show a tooltip(question text), when admin hovers on the column (i.e. question id).

Has anyone achieved this before? If so, could you please point me in right direction?

Thank in advance

Comment: Do you mean hover on columns or hover on rows?

Comment: Hover on columns

Comment: Tooltip should appear when you hover above column header or all column space?

Comment: It shows "asc" for all columns.. Can I change it to display question text?

Answer (score 1):

It is not easy to do in correct way. Magento has no native functionality to change colums title. But you can override

```
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract::renderHeader()
```

For example in grid class you can

```
    $column = $this->addColumn(
        'id',
        array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('yourmodule')
                    ->__('ID'),
            'width'  => '50px',
            'index'  => 'id'
        )
    );
   $column->setTitle('Title');
```

And rewrite block Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column with your block and method renderHeader() like this

```
public function renderHeader()
{
    if (false !== $this->getColumn()->getGrid()->getSortable() && false !== $this->getColumn()->getSortable()) {
        $className = 'not-sort';
        $dir = strtolower($this->getColumn()->getDir());
        $nDir= ($dir=='asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';
        if ($this->getColumn()->getDir()) {
            $className = 'sort-arrow-' . $dir;
        }
        $out = '<a href="#" name="' . $this->getColumn()->getId() . '" title="' . $this->getColumn()->getTitle()
               . '" class="' . $className . '"><span class="sort-title">'
               . $this->getColumn()->getHeader().'</span></a>';
    } else {
        $out = $this->getColumn()->getHeader();
    }
    return $out;
}
```